# gtk.StatusIcon with double click

Tags: python, gtk, icons, status

I'm using python GTK under Gnome (Gnome 3 in Fedora 15).
I'd like to catch events when the user double clic on the icon in the tray area.

I found that "activate" signals is called when the user do a single clic, but can't find the signal or a proper way to call a method when the user double clic on it.

How can I do ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Gtk+ itself doesn't even know if it was single or double clicked.
From the Gtk+ documentation about the ::activate signal:

> Gets emitted when the user activates the status icon. If and how status icons can activated is platform-dependent.

Interestingly Qt knows about this (it has Trigger and DoubleClick). Maybe you can work around this by using ::button-press-event instead and counting it, but I'm not sure this can be called the recommended way.

Also, a personal note as a user: I prefer status icons that are activated by a single click.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I'm working on a screen capture for linux that upload a file to a server, and the reason for the double clic was that if the user clic on my app by mistake, his mouse will became the cross cursor for selecting an area and force him to upload an image he doesn't necessarily want. That's why :)

Comment: You could grab the Escape key to get the user out of that situation